# How can I insert Image to ANY EditText in the system?

Tags: android

I make custom keyboard.
The main task is to show different images (like emoji).
Biggest problem that I have no idea how to do it) I hava simple keyboard which print chars already.
Is it possible to do it?

Its what a have till now:

```
public class PNGKeyboardService extends InputMethodService {

private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;
private InputConnection ic;
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

private KeyboardActionListener keyboardListener = new KeyboardActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

        builder.clear();
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            default:
                builder.append((char) primaryCode);
                builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(PNGKeyboardService.this, R.drawable.key_qwas), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                ic.commitText(builder, 1);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(keyboardListener);
    return kv;
}
```

Comment: Your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Comment: @EdGeorge add source code